# kendo window in iframe mode : the URL is not being requested from the server

Tags: kendo-ui

I think the following is a valid configuration:

```
    var wdiv = $("#messagewindow");
    if (!wdiv.data("kendoWindow")) {
        wdiv.kendoWindow({ 
            iframe: true,
            width: "777px",
            height: "666px",               
            title:  "foo title",           
            data: { startdate: urldate, eeid: eeid, deptid: deptid },
            url: "foo.htm",
            type: "GET"
        });
    }     

    wdiv.data("kendoWindow").open();
```

The window opens, but there's no network activity.  **Foo.htm is not being requested from the server** according to Fiddler.

Am I neglecting something in the configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not such things as url when creating.

http://jsbin.com/umuzil/1/edit

What you look for is called content. Url is used when [refresh](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#refresh)-ing the window.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification, Pechka.  I now see that the Parameters apply to the refresh() method.

Answer (score 2):

The option for specifying the url is `content`. Documentation in [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#content-objectstring).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @OnaBai. I was reading the "Parameters" section of that very page you cited: `Options for requesting data from the server. If omitted, the window uses the content property that was supplied when the window was created.`  But I see now that the Parameters apply only to refresh().